# Paragraph or chapter? Choosing the word

Tags: word-choice

Traditionally, information in Russian textbooks on history, geography is given in "paragraphs". But this word in Russian has the meaning different from that in English - in fact, those paragraphs are chapters.
Is it possible to use the word "paragraph" speaking of the structure of textbooks? I personally would use the word "chapter".

Comment: It's hard to tell without more context, but in English, a paragraph and a chapter are very distinctly different things.  A chapter has multiple paragraphs and is usually labeled "Chapter *N*"; a paragraph is one block of sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The English word for Russian "параграф" is **section**. So I think it would be appropriate to say that in textbooks the information is given in sections, or that the texts in the textbooks are divided in sections. I would not use here the noun 'chapter', which is translated into Russian as "глава". To my mind, that term mainly refers to belles-lettres.

Comment: Why don't you think textbooks have chapters, though?  In my experience with English-language textbooks, they certainly have chapters which are called such.

Comment: @Alex89: You are right, but why is the word "chapter" not acceptable in the textbook? The meaning of this word is 'a main division of a book, usually with a number or title'.

Answer (score 1):

Both words **chapter** and **paragraph** have identical definitions in either language.

If you are addressing a block of text on a page you can either say "**section**" or "**paragraph**".